# Tomcat error deploying war file javax.servlet not found

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, servlets

```
Mar 13, 2013 7:36:49 PM org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator validateManifestResources
INFO: ExtensionValidator[/edu][resin.jar]: Required extension [javax.servlet] not found.
Mar 13, 2013 7:36:49 PM org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator validateManifestResources
INFO: ExtensionValidator[/edu]: Failure to find [1] required extension(s).
Mar 13, 2013 7:36:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Mar 13, 2013 7:36:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/edu] startup failed due to previous errors
```

The above is from the catalina.log file.  I've successfully loaded tomcat 7 on mac and threw in a .war file into my webapps folder.  Tomcat built a file directory from it, but wont' deploy I'm assuming because of the above error.  First time working with .jsp and servlets, thanks ahead for your patience.

Comment: Looks like a problem in your war file. Have you been able to run it in your development environment or somewhere else before?

Comment: Tomcat is a servlet container so it supports both jsp and servlet on default. If your tomcat setup is correct it should work. Could you check your tomcat lib directory?

Comment: tomcat/lib has no javax.servlet, it does have servlet-api.jar though.  webapps/edu/WEB-INF/lib does have javax.servlet.jar and resin.jar, which seems to be trying to require javax.servlet.jar.

The war file was just handed off to me by one of our engineers, i'm assuming it works fine on his development environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel stupid, resin.jar = resin server. never heard of it. obviously didn't work on Tomcat.